# How setConnectTimeout can work?

Tags: android

I read many posts about setConnectTimeout but I really wonder how this method could work because we cannot initialize it before openConnection() exists.

```
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(5000);
urlConnection.setReadTimeout(2000);

...
```

So what is the purpose of setConnectTimeout()?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use URLConnection Timeout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6529733/how-to-use-urlconnection-timeout)

Answer (score 0):

You're just opening / initializing the connection. You haven't actually called `urlConnection.connect()` yet. You're only initializing things like the URL, headers, setting your request method, etc.

It'll come into effect once you actually run the connection.