# Killing a connection in Java after a specified amount of time

Tags: java, web, ftp, connection

So basically I'm writing a program which outputs a website. The website should be written directly onto the server.

I am using this code to write to the server:

```
URL  url = new URL("ftp://usr:pw@ftp.site.com/test/login.php;type=i");
    URLConnection urlc = url.openConnection();
    OutputStream os = urlc.getOutputStream(); // To upload
    OutputStream buffer = new BufferedOutputStream(os);
    PrintStream output = new PrintStream(buffer);
    output.print(sb);
```

But sometimes my program runs and never terminates, so I'm guessing the connection is not being successful. '

Could I create a timeout in the case that this occurs? ie like 30 seconds, the connection would be automatically terminated so that the program could terminate.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: URL con time out  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6529733/how-to-use-urlconnection-timeout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
con.setConnectTimeout(5000);//5 seconds
con.setReadTimeout(5000);
```

Answer (score 2):

`URLConnection` has a `setConnectTimeout` method. By using this method you can set the time:

```
urlc.setConnectTimeout(30); // Time is in milliseconds
urlc.setReadTimeout(30);
```

Comment: Are you sure the parameters are not in milliseconds :) 30 is too low and throws an exception instantly. Setting to 5000ms (ie 5s), as the post below shows works perfectly though.

Comment: indeed, I thought you wrote 30 since i wrote 30 seconds in my question, so I was not sure